# How do I parse a decimal number from a string to an integer in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, decimal, decimal-point

I want to convert a decimal string to an integer but I keep getting the following error:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
var myString = "18.7";
var myInteger = Int32.Parse(myString); //flaging an error here
Console.WriteLine(myInteger) //desired result = 18
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should parse it to a double type and cast it to an integer

```
var myString = "18.7";
var myInteger = (int)Convert.ToDouble(myString); 
Console.WriteLine(myInteger) //desired result = 18
```

The conversion will be like this

- "18.7" (a string value) to 18.7 (a double value)
- 18.7 (a double type) to 18 (an integer type - the decimal part gets removed)

In some cases, your strings may be like `18,7` which is relied on `CultureInfo` for conversion. That makes `18.7` unformattable.

As for culture independency, you can convert it like below

```
var myString = "18.7";
var myInteger = (int)Convert.ToDouble(myString,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); 
Console.WriteLine(myInteger) //desired result = 18
```

Comment: should note this truncates the decimal value to integer, so 18.7 becomes 18

Comment: When dealing with user input, you may prefer [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I had to add the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` parameter for it to work:

`var myDecimal = decimal.Parse("18.7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
`var myInt = Convert.ToInt32(myDecimal);`

Comment: Oh, I thought you set it for a particular culture, let me complete my answer there @Jdslk

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because the string “18.7” is not a valid integer format. Integers basically are whole numbers. So to convert a decimal string to an integer, you can use `Math.Floor()` or `Math.Ceiling()` methods, which truncate or round up the decimal value respectively.

For example:

`Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(“18.7”)); //will return 18`
`Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(“18.7”)); //will return 19`